# Aligning different and numbered equations in Latex

Tags: equations

I can align different lines of the same equation in **Latex** with this code:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{align}
 \frac{\partial a}{\partial b}(x)&=\frac{\partial a}{\partial c}\times \frac{\partial c}{\partial b} = \\ 
 &= \frac{\partial a}{\partial c}(x)\times \frac{\partial c}{\partial b}
\end{align}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

but I couldn't find any solution for **aligning different numbered equations** like these:

```
\begin{equation}
q_{new} = q \times q(\omega + \Omega) \Delta t
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
 v_{new} = v + V 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\omega_{new} = \omega + \Omega 
\end{equation}
```

I get this output, which is not aligned by equal sign:
[image]

Which is the right way to proceed?

**EDIT**

The solution was using

```
\begin{align}
\end{align}
```

Numeration is managed at the same time as equation environment so I can mix both, I didn't know that. Simpler and cleaner.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/5764) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: I am using this align but different equations on the same page do not align

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is one of those times "Latex is smarter than you and you should accept it". Why should these be aligned anyways? They are completely unrelated by the looks of it. If you need them to fit together, put them together in one `align`, otherwise don't worry; it will look nice anyway. Let Latex place your separate equations, or rewrite the text so that they can all fit in one single `align`.

BTW: You don't need to and shouldn't wrap `align` inside an `equation` environment. If you need subalignment (for example to the right of a left brace `{`, you should use the `aligned` environment).

EDIT: it seems you don't want any text between the equations and I understood you incorrectly. this is what you want if you don't need text between the separate equations:

```
\begin{align}
q_\text{new} &= q \times q(\omega + \Omega) \Delta t \\
v_\text{new} &= v + V \\
\omega_\text{new} &= \omega + \Omega 
\end{align}
```

Comment: Thanks. And how exactly would you use aligned environment. I need to keep numbered equations, so I guess I cannot remove the \begin{equation} statement...

Comment: @Jav_Rock yes you can remove `\begin{equation}`. The `align` environment takes care of numbering the same way `equation` does.

Comment: You are right. The problem is that it numbers every line but I corrected by putting \nonumber after the lines I dont want to be numbered

Comment: @Jav_Rock: Yeah, I always use `\notag`. Don't know what the difference between that and `nonumber` might be though...