# align environment: set position of & manually

Tags: equations, align

In the following code, the alignment position for & is computed automatically:

```
\begin{align*}
x^2 + y^2 &= 1 \\
y &= \sqrt{1 - x^2}.
\end{align*}
```

Now, I'd like to have all my equality signs (over many equations/aligns in many sections and subsections) aligned at the same position, preferably by just manually giving a position. **Is this possible, and how?**

Comment: it is not possible (without hackeray with `\intertext{...}`, as far as i know). in the case, that some one know, how to do this, i not recommend to doing this. the result will not be nice.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107033 https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/343911 https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122069

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61557/aligning-different-and-numbered-equations-in-latex

Comment: @TorbjørnT. and this is a duplicate of which? Now I don't know how to vote :(

Comment: @Skillmon: IMHO, the question is best answered in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107033/align-successive-equations-through-the-entire-document. However, I think it's bad to close/downvote duplicate questions, as they add synonyms/paraphrasing that will help other people to easier find an answer. Obviously, I didn't find an answer with search, so I asked, and now there are more search terms for this topic.